# How to parse HTML with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse some HTML using Nokogiri and am having some issues.    I want to go through each "employerReview" class and capture content under the "pros" and "cons".

I am having trouble just doing the first part: getting one item to return to the console.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'


doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Microsoft-Reviews-E1651.htm'))

doc.css('//*[@id="empReview_2320868"]/div[1]/p[1]/tt').each do |link|
puts link.content
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get closer to finding the data you are looking for by using CSS, instead of XPath:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Microsoft-Reviews-E1651.htm'))

doc.css('div.employerReview > div.description > p > strong').each do |item|
  puts item.content
  item.parent.css('tt').each do |details|
    puts details.content
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is you're using an XPath accessor for a method that expects CSS:

```
doc.css('//*[@id="empReview_2320868"]/div[1]/p[1]/tt')
```

You can use `search` or `xpath` for XPaths instead.

That doesn't find the nodes you want though. A simple test shows they don't exist:

```
doc.css("#empReview_2320868")
```

should return something, but it returns `[]`, meaning that ID doesn't exist in any tags.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source for the page, it seems it does: `<div id="empReview_2320868" class="employerReview" itemprop="review"....`

Answer (score 0):

You've passed `xpath` to a `css` selector.

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Microsoft-Reviews-E1651.htm'))
ps = doc.xpath('//div[@class="employerReview"]//div[@class="description"]/p[position()<3]')

ps.map{|p| p.text.strip}.each_slice(2) do |pros, cons|
  puts pros
  puts cons
end
```

The xpath specified has included the `Pros -` and `Cons -` part, if that's not what you want, you can change the xpath to be

```
//div[@class="employerReview"]//div[@class="description"]/p[position()<3]/tt
```